# Mysql select only two items from table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select only two items from table, not with * and row and etc...

I tried this, but its not working:

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, email FROM users WHERE nev = '$nev' LIMIT 1") or die (mysql_error());
    $id = mysql_result($query, 0);
    $email = mysql_result($query, 1);
```

Any idea?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Do you get an error?  An incorrect result (for what data?)?  The query itself looks basically ok (though susceptible to SQL injection attacks if you're not careful to validate the contents of `$nev`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to  [mysql_result documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php)

the parameters can be described like this
mysql_result ($result, $row , $field)
You look for the 1st and 2nd row of an undefined field , which means 1st field of your select (id)
when i suppose you look for the 1st row (and only since you have put LIMIt 1) of the 1st and 2nd field (id, email that you selected)

```
$id =mysql_result($query , 0 , 0 )
$email = mysql_result($query , 0, 1 )
```